Are there words that break the usual spelling differences between British and American English?
After being corrected by a spellchecker set to British English, I was surprised to find that "parallelisable" was not accepted, and was corrected to "parallelizable".  Is this just an artefact of the spell checker being insufficiently localised? (I suspect it might be due to its infrequent use)
The reason I thought to ask is because I came across a discussion in which a speaker of American English claimed that they kept the spelling of "glamour" while dropping the 'u' from other similar words. Upon fact-checking it seems that both variations are accepted, but it makes me wonder the following:
Which words do not follow the conventional rules on the delta between British and American English? For example, is parallelizable the only acceptable spelling in both dictionaries?
I'm looking words that are purely -ise in the US and UK, or purely -ize in both. Or words that are only ever -our instead of -or, like glamour. Or words that deviate from any other localisation rules.

I know plenty of people, including myself as a teenager, who personally prefer spelling that vary with their own region. That doesn't constitute an "accepted regional variant," just malign eccentricity. Also: in either spelling, "parallelizable" seems fairly rare. When I looked it up I got "parallelizable manifold," a math term. Maybe automated processes like spellcheckers are being thrown by encountering a very small data set, in which one usage takes on an outsized proportion.

The Alan Turing Institute, who ought to know, seem OK with the -isable version when mentioning [d]evelopment of composable, parallelisable and user-friendly inference, and growing the community of the Turing.jl probabilistic programming language.

Related: Can all verbs ending in "-ise" be written with the suffix "ize"?

After starting a new document in Microsoft Word 2013, language set to UK English, with these words Is parallelisable a word? I got no little coloured underlines, and the Spell Check feature says 'Spelling and grammar check complete. You're good to go'. The Notepad app in Windows 11 ignores the -isable spelling, but if I add an extra 'e' at the end, it flags it as a mis-spelling and suggests parallelizable. Removing the extra 'e' makes everything OK again.

There are lots of words that can be spelt either -ise or -ize in UK English, such as realise/realize. Is that what you're looking for, or do you want a word that's purely -ise in the US and purely -ize in the UK?

@StuartF - it's possibly good to say that many alleged US/British English 'differences' are really tendencies rather than cast-iron 'rules'.

Which spellchecker were you using?

Well, I’d imagine that new words from the U S follow US usage in the UK, whereas they keep their old spelling with old words. Sometimes both countries adopt options. Beyond that, this is a closable question asking for a list.

Glamour is the common American English spelling. Glamor would generally not be accepted.

But how many people even use a word like parallelizable? Not exactly the best example.

Yes, there are words in both American English (AmE) and British English (BrE) where the spelling is the same despite the usual differences in suffixes like -ise/-ize, -our/-or, etc. The Wikipedia article 'American and British English spelling differences' provides a thorough overview and highlights key exceptions. Below, I’ve cited the relevant parts and exceptions for the -our/-or and -ize/-ise suffixes:

American spelling avoids -ise endings in words like organize, realize and recognize.
British spelling mostly uses -ise (organise, realise, recognise), though -ize is sometimes used. The ratio between -ise and -ize stood at 3:2 in the British National Corpus up to 2002.
Some verbs take only -s- worldwide: advertise, advise, arise, chastise, circumcise, comprise, compromise, demise, despise, devise, disguise, excise, exercise, franchise, guise, improvise, incise, promise, reprise, revise, rise, supervise, surmise, surprise, televise, and wise. (In a few of these, -ise is not a suffix, while some have an -ise suffix with a different etymology, and the rest derive from -ίζειν.)
American usage, in most cases, keeps the u in the word glamour, which comes from Scots, not Latin or French. Glamor is sometimes used in imitation of the spelling reform of other -our words to -or. Nevertheless, the adjective glamorous often drops the first "u". Saviour is a somewhat common variant of savior in the US. The British spelling is very common for honour (and favour) in the formal language of wedding invitations in the US.
The name of the herb savory is spelled thus everywhere, although the related adjective savo(u)ry, like savo(u)r, has a u in the UK.
The agent suffix -or (separator, elevator, translator, animator, etc.) is spelled thus both in American and British English.

Note: There may also be exceptions based on dialects and registers, as well as exceptions to the exceptions listed above. For instance, OED lists advertize as a form of advertise but there are no contemporary citations:

1500s– advertize (now chiefly U.S.)

Wiktionary says the spelling advertize is archaic, now nonstandard, sometimes proscribed.

One might attribute the presence of u in US wedding invitations less to formality and more to pretention.  Another spelling with a similarly ambiguous explanation is theatre: is it an affectation, or does it result from the greater exposure to British writing among American practitioners and amateurs of the dramatic arts?
